# iOS Phonegap returning weird purchase receipts

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-plugins, receipt

I've been seeing several purchase attempts from my Phonegap iOS app with this odd transaction receipt, which appears to be invalid when I try to verify it at the itunes endpoint.

```
window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onPurchased = function (transactionId, productId, receipt) {
  // receipt is MC4wMDAwMDA= which base64 decodes to 0.000000
}
```

I'm suspecting a hack, but I want to verify that we aren't doing anything wrong.

This is using the official InAppPurchaseManager plugin from the phonegap-plugins repo on Cordova 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the plugin that you're using but I don't think you're doing anything wrong.  There are several programs out there that forge receipts in an attempt to steal in-app purchases.  Apple recommends validating receipts via your own server to make it more difficult for hackers and hacks to scam your products.  You can read about Apple's receipt validation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW3) and their recommended best practices [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012484).

Receipts like `MC4wMDAwMDA=` or ones starting with `Y29tLnVydXMuaWFwLj` are common forged receipt signatures and will fail validation when submitted to Apple.

Comment: We do verify receipts and these didn't pass. I just wanted to be sure I wasn't somehow breaking the receipt before it got the verification process and screwing users out of valid purchases.